# Counting consonants and vowels in a split string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I read in a .csv file. I have the following data frame that counts vowels and consonants in a string in the column `Description`.  This works great, but my problem is I want to split `Description` into 8 columns and count the consonants and vowels for each column.  The second part of my code allows for me to split `Description` into 8 columns.  How can I count the vowels and consonants on all 8 columns the `Description` is split into?

```
import pandas as pd
import re

def anti_vowel(s):
    result = re.sub(r'[AEIOU]', '', s, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    return result

data = pd.read_csv('http://core.secure.ehc.com/src/util/detail-price-list/TristarDivision_SummitMedicalCenter_CM.csv')

data.dropna(inplace = True)

data['Vowels'] = data['Description'].str.count(r'[aeiou]', flags=re.I)
data['Consonant'] = data['Description'].str.count(r'[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxzy]', flags=re.I)

print (data)
```

This is the code I'm using to split the column `Description` into 8 columns.

```
import pandas as pd
data = data["Description"].str.split(" ", n = 8, expand = True)
data = pd.read_csv('http://core.secure.ehc.com/src/util/detail-price-list/TristarDivision_SummitMedicalCenter_CM.csv')

data.dropna(inplace = True)

data = data["Description"].str.split(" ", n = 8, expand = True)

print (data)
```

Now how can I put it all together?

In order to read each column of the 8 and count consonants I know i can use the following replacing the 0 with 0-7:

```
testconsonant = data[0].str.count(r'[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxzy]', flags=re.I)
testvowel = data[0].str.count(r'[aeiou]', flags=re.I)
```

Desired output would be:

```
Description [0] vowel count consonant count Description [1] vowel count consonant count Description [2] vowel count consonant count Description [3] vowel count consonant count Description [4] vowel count consonant count all the way to description [7]
```

Comment: Interesting but we don't have your input file `TristarDivision_SummitMedicalCenter_CM.csv` so we can't execute this, it isn't an [MCVE (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Can you please just make up a few lines of sample input? Then you can do `pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(your_data), ...)`

Comment: And please state what is the problem? show us the current output and expected output. Or else the error/stacktrace if it throws one.

Comment: 1. You do have the input file if you have an internet connection.  2. There shouldn't be a need to make up a few sample line.  The question was MCVE if you ran both sets of code you would of had the output. 3. You could of been helpful and suggested stack/unstack as piR did below.

Comment: 1. No, giving an (ephemeral, breakable, possibly stale) URL is **not MCVE**. URLs, websites and companies grow old, decay, break, go out of existence. But if you had just shown the text input here in a short multiline string and used `pd.compat.StringIO`, it could never break. I'm helping you. 2. Yes there is, see 1., otherwise this isn't MCVE. How many questions from 10 years ago's URLs still work? Very few. 3. I am being helpful to you, the site is supposed to be a reusable resource, think of other people in a few years trying to infer what this does once your file is no longer available.

Comment: By the way, not all users behind corporate firewalls have unrestricted internet access to arbitrary URLs , often to just a subset of whitelisted sites, for security policy. Than can make this irreproducible and hence not MCVE to some users.

Comment: It has been [agreed as guidelines for years](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277644/remind-people-that-included-files-are-part-of-an-mcve) that not providing the input data file or snippet (where needed) is a violation of MCVE. Regardless [whether  the MCVE guidelines spell that out for input data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/386953/202229). I'm genuinely trying to help you get answers while keeping the site useable for current and future users. Please just add the data snippet in the question already.

Comment: Just to underline the point, while the value to the questioner is being able to obtain an answer to an immediate question, once the URL goes stale (or, worse, changes) the question loses any educational value it might have for other users. Treating SO like a help desk isn't endearing. Please, add more value!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not reproducible with the data source being expired

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `stack` then `unstack`

```
stacked = data.stack()
pd.concat({
    'Vowels': stacked.str.count('[aeiou]', flags=re.I),
    'Consonant': stacked.str.count('[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxzy]', flags=re.I)
}, axis=1).unstack()
```

---

```
      Consonant                                         Vowels                                        
              0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8      0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
0           3.0  5.0  5.0  1.0  2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1           8.0  5.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  NaN    0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  NaN
2           8.0  5.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  NaN    0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  NaN
3           8.0  5.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  NaN    0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  NaN
4           3.0  5.0  3.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  NaN    0.0  0.0  2.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  NaN
5           3.0  5.0  3.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  NaN    0.0  0.0  2.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  NaN
6           3.0  4.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  NaN  NaN    3.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  NaN  NaN
7           3.0  3.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  NaN  NaN    3.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  NaN  NaN
8           3.0  3.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0    3.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
9           3.0  3.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  NaN  NaN    3.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  NaN  NaN
10          3.0  3.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  NaN    3.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  NaN
11          3.0  3.0  0.0  2.0  2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    3.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
12          3.0  3.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  NaN    3.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  NaN
13          3.0  3.0  0.0  2.0  2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    3.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
14          3.0  5.0  0.0  2.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0    3.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
15          3.0  3.0  0.0  3.0  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    3.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

If you want to combine this with the `data` dataframe, you can do:

```
stacked = data.stack()
pd.concat({
    'Data': data,
    'Vowels': stacked.str.count('[aeiou]', flags=re.I),
    'Consonant': stacked.str.count('[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxzy]', flags=re.I)
}, axis=1).unstack()
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you piR!  If I want to add the stack to the current data frame how would I go about doing that?

Comment: @user1470034 see if my update get's you what you need

Comment: piRSquare that's exactly what i was attempting to do, you're wonderful have a great 4th.